# How to compare a user field against a number in routes?

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

So the idea here is that i want to check a users role_id against a number so it would look something like

```
if ($user->role_id >1 ){
    Route::post('/moreDetails', 'HomeController@update');
}
```

How would i go about doing this?

Comment: You should use middleware to restrict the user access depending on the user role: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware

Comment: You may also be interested by [Abilities and Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization). Or use a package to handle it, like [Bouncer](https://packagist.org/packages/silber/bouncer)